# What is a good policy to control visibility of GUI items (forms or web based) based on users roles

Tags: user-interface

I had thought about decorating various control items with attributes to declare group ownership, but this seems a bit onerous and not very extensible/maintainable (I'd have to subclass the controls and decorate them by hand).

Another policy would be to have  a white list of groups a control is visible for  persisted away against a form id in a db.  A check for the visiblity could then be done in a base class from which all my forms inherit, thereby ensuring my class code wasnt muddied with this "adminsitration"

Just seems a lot better than having to write case/if statements based on role to determine what should be visible to users depending on their privileges, in situ. 
This seems a pretty common problem and wondered if there were any good patterns to employ.

Thanks

Comment: Will a flag in the ground help? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider Drupal for building a web-based application whereby GUI capability is governed by user role. The Drupal (an general open source content management system and web framework) has powerful user management whereby each user can be allocated one or more roles. You could then make use of a role to determine the behaviour of a web form and the availability of certain fields for that role. User's with that role would see  certain GUI items, whereas others would not.

Some links to follow as a starting point:

- http://www.drupal.org
- http://drupal.org/project/webform

I should add that Drupal can do many things and not just this specific problem area. Drupal is a broad ranging framework for builing your own websites on your own hosting.

Comment: @brumScouse thank you for accepting my answer. For more on Drupal web forms you may be interested in the following (e)book: http://www.packtpub.com/drupal-7-webform-popular-contributed-modules-cookbook/book (and see other Packt titles for Drupal guides). See also http://oreilly.com as they have a good range too. See also http://nodeone.se for videos on Drupal (free but good) and http://lynda.com (also good but subscription) (I don't work for them and do not gain financially from them.)